# Disabling drag-to-scroll in ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, mouseevent, drag, selectionchanged

I'm working in WPF to create a ListView component. The items in the list are based on another user control that reacts to MouseLeftDown events. The List also reacts to SelectionChanged events.

Right now, if I mouse down on any item on the list and move the cursor, the other items I pass along react to the SelectionChanged event (which is expected since the selection is changing as per the Mouse Down event in List view). I need to be able to disable this reaction when its down through a drag-to-scroll behavior, but to keep it active when the user selects an item on the list.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks everyone,

RK

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the ways that could help you is to implement your own handlers of MouseUp and MouseDown events of your items to select item on MouseUp instead of MouseDown. You could start from a sample like this:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyListViewItem();
    }
}

public class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }
}
```